# Disable Unity Debug Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, debugging, lwrp, urp

For about an hour ago a Debug Canvas started Instantiating on Play.
I've searched around on the internet but can't seem to find anything.
Are there by any chance some of you who might know how to disable it as it's taking up about half of the screen?

Edit:
I tried to install the project on another computer and it doesn't show up. So idk if it has anything to do with the project or Unity itself.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQEHP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to one of your scripts on Awake or Start:

```
UnityEngine.Rendering.DebugManager.instance.enableRuntimeUI = false;
```

This is mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@14.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.DebugManager.html#UnityEngine_Rendering_DebugManager_displayRuntimeUI)

You have to be on CoreRP 12 or later as mentioned [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@12.1/manual/whats-new-12.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try Left Ctrl + Backspace to toogle it, or remove the Universal RP (Render Pipeline) package or disable it by code:

```
bool debugupdater_disabled = false;
 
private void Update()
    {
        if (debugupdater_disabled)
            return;
 
        GameObject debugUpdater = GameObject.Find("[Debug Updater]");
        if(debugUpdater != null)
        {
            Destroy(debugUpdater);
            debugupdater_disabled = true;
            Debug.Log("done");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried the Left CTRL + Backspace but it isn't working. I kind of need URP and it seems very inefficient disabling it via code. There must be a way to disable it just like I enabled it somehow. It started showing up after I downloaded the new Input System but that just seems to be a coincidence.